# Avoid None in cursor.description?

Tags: python, sqlite, database-cursor

I'm using SQLite3 in Python.

My table :

```sql
create table student(
    rno int,
    name char(20), 
    grade char,
    gender char,
    avg decimal(5,2),
    dob date
);
```

Where cursor is the name of my cursor object.

I've used `cursor.description` to display the column names. But there are seven strings in each tuple in which six are None.

```py
print(cursor.description)
```

Output (formatted):

```
(
  ('rno', None, None, None, None, None, None), 
  ('name', None, None, None, None, None, None), 
  ('grade', None, None, None, None, None, None), 
  ('gender', None, None, None, None, None, None), 
  ('avg', None, None, None, None, None, None), 
  ('dob', None, None, None, None, None, None)
)
```

From  the [DB-API PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-attributes), it is clear that first two elements of each tuple are required. But it's not for me. Why?

Also, what changes shall I make in my table to get the values for the other elements which are set as None?

Comment: Which of the 7 items are important to you? Do you need more than the column name and data type?

Answer (score 4):

The sqlite3 for DB API2.0 guarantees only first item.

> it returns a 7-tuple for each column where the last six items of each
> tuple are None.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.description

To print all the details, you should have some data I guess.
May be add some data and execute a select statements

Comment: And I'm dealing with SQLite3 in Python not about MySQL. Kindly adjust your answer

Comment: I just put it as an example to print description....for python DB API 2.0....

Comment: As I understand the question is, how to get more information in the cursor.description. And this answer says: You will not get any more information then the column names. The lib SQLite3 does not provide more.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently type_code being returned as None on sqllite 3 is a bug,Refer the link for more details.

[bug Details](https://bugs.python.org/issue32083)

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach. Still making use of the `cursor.description` in your original code.

1. Create a function to show all the records in the database

```
def show_all():
    # connect to db
    conn = sqlite3.connect('student.db')

    # create cursor
    c = conn.cursor()

    # query the db
    c.execute("SELECT rowid, * FROM student")

    items = c.fetchall()

    for item in items:
         print(item)
```

2. Then before closing the connection for the table/database you are working with

```
    # column names
    col_desc = []
    columns = c.description
    for column in columns:
        col_desc.append(column[0])
    print(col_desc)
```

3. In a separate file you could then import the `database` you are working with and execute the function

```
import student

students.show_all()
```

Comment: Kindly read my question once again... I didn't ask code to display the column names

Answer (score 0):

In their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65095484/5320906), user [VN'sCorner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2236726/vnscorner) observes that the second element of the tuple - the type code - being `None` was a bug.  In fact it was *reported* as a [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue32083), but closed as a duplicate of another [bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue11691) which was in turn closed as "Won't Fix" by Gerhard Häring ([link](https://bugs.python.org/issue11691#msg248824)):

> There is no guarantee that all any column in a SQlite resultset always has the same type. That's why I decided to err on the side of setting the type code to "undefined".

SQLite's [flexible typing](https://sqlite.org/flextypegood.html) is what the resolution is referring to, demonstrable by inserting some sample data from Python:

```
>>> cur.execute('create table t (col text)')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f00525c3f40>
>>> cur.execute('insert into t values (?)', ('spam',))
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f00525c3f40>
>>> cur.execute('insert into t values (?)', (b'spam',))
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f00525c3f40>
>>> conn.commit()
```

and viewing the types in the SQLite3 shell:

```sql
sqlite> select col, typeof(col) from t;
spam|text
spam|blob
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how I've got only the column

```
table_columns = [x[0] for x in con.execute('select * from table').description ]
```

where con is my connection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about sqlite, but for the mariadb connector, if the result set is empty and `cursor.description` is `None` or `[]`, but you want the column names, you can try executing the query again with the `LIMIT` clause set to `0`, which will return an empty result set with the column names.

```py
import mysql.connector

# Connect to the database
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='your_username', password='your_password',
                              host='your_host', database='your_database')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

# Execute the query
query = ("""
    SELECT column1, column2, column3
    FROM your_table
    WHERE some_condition
    """)
cursor.execute(query)

# Fetch all rows (which will be none)
rows = cursor.fetchall()

# If result set is empty, re-run the query plan
# with LIMIT 0 to get column names
if len(rows) == 0 or not cursor.description:
    cursor.execute(query + " LIMIT 0")

# Get the column names from the cursor description
column_names = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
```